# files from old debian package which is not there in new version getting deleted

Tags: ubuntu, debian

When installing a debian, will the files from old version of this debian package which is not there in new version get deleted.?

For example I install deb-1.1 and files1 and file2 comes from that debian. Now if I install an updated version of same debian say deb-1.2 which does not contain file1 and file2. So will file1 and file2 get deleted or will they remain there in the server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they will. That's exactly what package managers are there for.

Comment: The author asks if files not present in later versions of packages are deleted. My answer is: yes

Answer (score -1):

If you are updating your system through the package manager then you will lose your files.

If you have dropped these packages onto your system from a previous install instance they won't fall under the package manager remit. From comments below it seems the above is more suitable to you, they will be removed.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: It does, I just slightly misunderstood his question. Where the package manager is designed to keep your system up to date it is not designed to eliminate custom user settings/files. If, as I thought, he was using separate install instances and carrying packages over my answer stands. Since he is running a system update on the same instance your answer is more accurate.

Comment: Custom user settings are not part of packages

Comment: I know, that was the point.